# Arranging a character array using bubble sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, char, bubble-sort

Here is my code so far. I am perfectly able to sort files holding numbers but clueless when it comes to characters. It takes in a file of my choosing and outputs another file with the sorted array. But so far all I'm getting are blank files and I can't figure out why.

So how can I fix my code to sort an array of characters and then output it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bubble_sort(char *a, int n);

int main(void) {
    char a[10];
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[10];
    int i;
    char inname;
    char outname;

    printf("Enter input name: ");
    scanf("%s", &inname);
    printf("Enter output name: ");
    scanf("%s", &outname);

    FILE *in, *out;

    out = fopen(&outname, "w");

    if ((in = fopen(&inname, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");

    }


    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%s ", &a[i]);
        }

        bubble_sort(a, n);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", a[i]);
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", a[i]);
        }
    }

        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        return 0;
    }


int bubble_sort(char *a, int n) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;

        for (j = 1; j<n; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i<n - j; i++)
            {
                if ((int)a[i] >= (int)a[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
    return a[i];
}
```

Comment: Tip: Change `int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[10];` --> `int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];`

Comment: It looks like confusion between *characters* and *strings* is the main reasn of the problem.

Comment: Quite probably you want to change `fscanf(in, "%s ", &a[i]);` to `fscanf(in, "%c", &a[i]);`

Comment: @JohnHascall That was it. That is all it took. I'm fairly new to programming and I knew it was going to be something tiny. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem, as I can see, is with

```
scanf("%s", &inname);
```

In your code, `inname` is a single `char`, which cannot hold *string* inputs. You'll be needing an array.

You need to change

```
char inname;
char outname;
```

to

```
#define NAMSIZ 32

char inname[NAMSIZ] = {0};
char outname[NAMSIZ] = {0};
```

and then,

```
scanf("%31s", inname);
```

and accordingly.

Same problem exist with `fscanf(in, "%s ", &a[i]);`, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed what you suggested but its still not working as I had hoped. What did you mean by "Same problem exist with `fscanf(in, "%s ", &a[i]);` , too." (I'm fairly new to coding to be honest :P)